# Routing with and without controller name in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have some problems settings up my routes. Could you tell my how to set up my routes to point urls to actions as follows:

- "/" (or "/Start") => PublicController.Start()
- "/About" => PublicController.About()
- "/MyPage" (or "/MyPage/Summary") => MyPageController.Summary()
- "/MyPage/Invoices" => MyPageController.Invoices()
- "/MyPage/Invoice/72" => MyPageController.Invoice(int id)

It's the url "/About" that messes things up for me, i.e. a url that does not specify the controller. If I make that one work the others that do specify controller stop working. I could just create a separate controller for "/About" I guess, but I'd rather not if I don't have to (I have more urls following that pattern).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should do it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "About",
    url: "About",
    defaults: new { controller = "Public", action = "About" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyPageSummary",
    url: "MyPage",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyPage", action = "Summary" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Public", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: How can we achieve this with Attribute Routing?

Comment: In RouteConfig.cs before `routes.MapRoute` insert `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`. and than you can use attribute routing before action `[Route("~/About")]`. you need to prefix with a tilde to override the controller route. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712201/9258504