# How to redirect to index actionresult while not displaying index in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically, in my controller I'm redirecting to the Index action:

```
return RedirectToAction("", new { id = id });
```

This works great except for the fact that the URL bar displays `controllername/index/id`. I would like to be able to avoid displaying "Index" in the URL. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: For reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836401/routing-with-and-without-controller-name-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 4):

Add a route without the action name in your `global.asax.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute("NoActionInURL", "ControllerName/{id}", 
       new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "without the action name"? "I would like to be able to **avoid displaying** "Index" in the URL."

Comment: My mistake, I thought he wanted to hide the *controller*. Have updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'm sorry for the late reply.
A question though:
I'm redirecting to it using:
return RedirectToAction("", new { id = id });

However when I redirect it still displays index?