# ASP.NET Core MVC wrong link is generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller with this code. I want all actions to be `/Action/Controller` or `/{culture}/Action/Controller` except for Login which should be `/Login` or `/{culture}/Login`. Route works fine but Link is generated always as `/Accounts/Login` or `/{culture}/Accounts/Login`...

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[Route("/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Login", Order = 0)]
    [Route("/{culture}/Login", Order = 1)]
    public IActionResult Login(short? showLostPasswordInfo)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Link looks like this

```
<a asp-action="Login">...</a> //outputs /Accounts/Login
```

I want it to point to /Login but it keeps generating wrong link.

Configuration in Startup.cs looks like this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
     endpoints.MapControllers();
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
          endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "default",
          pattern: "{controller}/{action}");
          endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "cultureDefault",
          pattern: "{culture:culture}/{controller}/{action}");
     });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a different route to a specific action mvc 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709085/creating-a-different-route-to-a-specific-action-mvc-6)

Comment: No, been there. Doesn't work for me. But thanks.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the asp-controller tag helper with an empty value `<a asp-action="Login" asp-controller="">...</a>` something like this?

Comment: Yes, I did. It adds controller name automatically so it's definitely not a problem

Answer (score 0):

> Link is generated always as /Accounts/Login or
> /{culture}/Accounts/Login...
>
> ```
> [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
> [Route("/[controller]/[action]")]
> ```

Beacuse you put the ***[controller]*** in front of the ***[action]***,so the link as */controller/action*

You can try to change the code that  in front of  the controller as  below.  To show other works well, I add index() .

```
        [Route("[action]/[controller]")]
        
        public class AccountsController : Controller
        {
            
            [Route("/Login", Order = 0)]
            [Route("/{culture}/Login", Order = 1)]
    
            public IActionResult Login(short? showLostPasswordInfo)
            {
                return View();
            }
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
             ....
         }
```

To see the result clearly, I add something in _layout.cshtml as below.

```
 
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Index">Index2</a>
</li>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. There was another Login method in AccountsController for HttpPost which didn't have any Route attribute. Adding same attributes to second method solved the problem.