# How to override Controller's name in asp.net mvc core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, attributerouting

In my MVC controller, i have two action methods which are rendering **View**, other 6 Action Methods are either `HttpGet` or `HttpPost`. I want to do the below

for ActionMethods rendering View it will be **"controller/action"**. But for the **GET/POST**, i want it to be **api/whatevernameilike**.

Is it acheivable in `asp.net mvc core`?

TIA

Comment: Have you tried route attribute? [Route("/api/whatevernameilike")]

Comment: Yes, i have done. It's not working

Comment: Check this [routing-with-and-without-controller-name-in-asp-net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836401/routing-with-and-without-controller-name-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 1):

Worth trying as well if the previous methods aren't working:

```
[HttpGet("/api/whatevernameilike")]
```

Comment: This solution is Not Working

Comment: I am using version 3.1. [HttpGet("/api/..")] and [HttpGet("~/api/..")] both works.

Answer (score 1):

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) has an example for this:

> Use a tilde (~) on the method attribute to override the route prefix:
>
> ```
> [RoutePrefix("api/books")]
> public class BooksController : ApiController
> {
>     // GET /api/authors/1/books
>     [Route("~/api/authors/{authorId:int}/books")]
>     public IEnumerable<Book> GetByAuthor(int authorId) { ... }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) shows the following:

> ```
> [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
> public class HomeController : Controller
> {
>     [Route("~/")]
>     [Route("/Home")]
>     [Route("~/Home/Index")]
>     public IActionResult Index()
>     {
>         return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
>     }
>
>     public IActionResult About()
>     {
>         return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In the preceding code, the Index method templates must prepend / or ~/ to the route templates. Route templates applied to an action that begin with / or ~/ don't get combined with route templates applied to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route attribute on top of your controller
ex:

```
[Route("Api/Yourchosenname")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Action()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: but, that is creating the route as controllername/api/mychosenname